# React Native 0.52.0 - Text truncates when fontWeight set to bold

Tags: react-native

I just created a new React Native project and was working on the UI bit. I tried to write some text within `<Text>Hello world!</Text>` and it was working fine:

> Hello world!

But when I added `fontWeight: 'bold'` to the same, it truncated and showed something like this:

> **Hel..**

I've only tested this in android.

My React project version details:

> react-native-cli: 2.0.1
>
> react-native: 0.52.0

I have no idea why the text is truncating itself. Is this a known issue in the `0.52.0` because I've been using the same method to set text bold and the issue never occurred in `0.48.2`

**EDIT:**
I just realized, this happens when I have  inside a  with a style property `alignItems: 'center'` . I have no idea why this still happens though. Here's my code:

```
<View style={{alignItems:'center'}}>
    <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Helloworld!</Text>
</View>
```

Thanks!

Comment: how did you add the `fontWeight` style property to `Text`? Using `<Text style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}> ...` works as expected.

Comment: You need to remove ellipsizeMode={'tail'} if declared anywhere.

Comment: I've defined it using a StyleSheet. The weird part is that it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't. Also, it doesn't have ellipsizeMode anywhere, I am coding something from scratch, so it doesn't have any other property by default.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard - I've updated the question with the exact problem. Please check it out now!

Answer (score 0):

my coworker had the same problem, we solved by changing the font (through font-family). Most probably a bug from react...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex:1` and `flexDirection:"column"` at view level style if you want your content to come line by line. like this:-

```
<View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:"column"}}>
    <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Helloworld!</Text>
</View>
```

or if you don't want to use `flexDirection` then you can use `alignSelf: 'stretch', textAlign: 'center'`. like this:-

```
 <View style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch', textAlign: 'center'}}>
        <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Helloworld!</Text>
    </View>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `flexGrow:1` on the `Text` element, e.g.:

```html
<Text style={{flexGrow:1, fontWeight:'bold'}}> General Checkup </Text>
```